# How to import 3D object (.obj) to ARKit on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit

I'm a beginner iOS developer.

I'm trying to import and show the 3D object (https://poly.google.com/view/1zS7ucaAd4J) on Xcode by using ARKit.

Although I converted the 3D object from .obj to .scn, the texture of the 3D object is crashed.

[image: the screen capture of my Xcode]

I'd appreciate it if you would point out my wrong setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How did you convert your object to .scn file? 
I Use **[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)** application to convert **.obj** files to **.dae** which can be directly imported to the ARKit project and it works pretty good. You can also convert the **.dae** file to **.scn** very simply by xcode.

Comment: As you advised, I could import the 3D object after converting the .obj file to .dae by using  Blender. Thank you very much!!

Comment: you can convert online .obj to .dae there are lots of online tools available no need to download blender : check this link to convert model extension http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/